# How to check whether a file exists or not without knowing its directory in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any function that will respond whether a file exists or not without knowing its directory using PHP?

So far there are two functions in PHP **is_file()** and **is_dir()** to work with files. But this time I think these two will not working efficiently to fulfill my requirements. Why?

Suppose In the root directory of my project there are 12 sub-directories, and each sub-directories can have their own sub-directories along with other valid files.

Now I will put a file name [ only file name, not full path ] in a **textbox** and when I click on the search button it will return the full path if the file exists on either **root_directory** or any **sub_directory** of the root directory or the **available_other_sub_directory** of the **subdirectory_of_root_directory**.

Is it possible to do handle this by any built-in function of PHP? If yes then can anyone tell me how?

- Thanks

Comment: No, there is no build-in function that does exactly this. That's why PHP allows you to build custom functions. Simply scan the root and all sub-directories for the file, and it you find it return the path. There is a function that approached what you want called `glob()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `glob()` function [PHP glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: A `blob()` function? :)

Comment: :) fixed, c/p typo